# Assassinate Shakespeare!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, google-ngram

Factoid: The noun "assassination" first appeared in print in Shakespeare's Macbeth.

However, forget that. The puzzle is to reproduce the following ngram.

[image]

The correct answer will be a link to the [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams) website. On following the link, the above graph will be reproduced exactly. Of course I have edited my version of the image to conceal the search term I used. On following your link, the text-box will be shown filled in, thus creating the graph. All other parameters are shown exactly as I submitted them.

Detail

> [image]

Comment: Any hints like single word or length of phrase? Like this its just a huge pile of bruteforcing.

Comment: There is a big hint in plain view. If I made it explicit, someone would get the answer in an instant. Let's see how things progress without any further information. Knowing the people here, it's going to get solved very quickly anyway. Maybe I'll swap the 'enigmatic' tag for a more telling one if no-one makes any progress.

Comment: O, thou beslubbering, earth-vexing, in-plain-view big hint. Thou art unfit for any place but hell. (I'm going to waste an entire afternoon here, I know.)

Comment: Terrific idea for a puzzle!  +1

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Got it:

> [Kill Bill](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Kill%20Bill&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CKill%20Bill%3B%2Cc0)

I'm not sure much explanation is needed.

> Just look at the title

Comment: Even though it looks close its still way off. Try looking at the percentages once.

Comment: @TheDarkTruth I was thinking too hard.

Comment: Thats one damn jump to get from shakespeare over his first name William to the short form Bill. Congrats. But why the hell was that such a (relatively) hot topic 1965-1973?

Comment: @TheDarkTruth It might have been easier to make the jump as I took the Kids to see http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2978576/ at the weekend! Can't see why it was hot in the 60's & 70's

Comment: Not sure I can go along with describing 0.0000000500% as 'hot'.  Note also that Google is disregarding punctuation.