# Google ngram puzzle No 2

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, google-ngram

Encouraged by the reasonable success of my first ngram puzzle [Assassinate Shakespeare!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23022/assassinate-shakespeare) I've decided to explore the idea further.

Here is a new ngram. Your task is to reproduce it exactly by entering the relevant search terms into Google ngram.

[image: ngram]

Detail

[image: ngram settings]

**The answer**

The correct answer will be a link to the [Google ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams) showing the exact same graph as I have given but with the mystery text filled in.

**How to proceed**

This puzzle is designed to be difficult but not impossible. I thought my first ngram puzzle was difficult and yet within three hours someone had solved it. This time I decided to pitch the level at those in the community who are super-quick and give them a little more of a challenge.

Finding a solution does not rely on brute-force methods. If you observe all aspects of the diagram carefully and take note of the Knowledge tag, you should be able to arrive at a partial answer and then a very small amount of fine-tuning will complete the solution.

Comment: The peaks are roughly at 1974, 1977, 1981, 1989.  Would this be helpful?

Comment: @Gamow - Keep thinking along those lines.

Comment: Is it Ford, Carter, Reagan, Bush?

Comment: You are still on the right track. You can check if an answer is correct by plotting it on ngram. Remember to set the other parameters exactly as I show in the diagram.

Comment: Really nice!  But I do not think that you should make them much tougher...

Comment: Haha! Why not? Is there a rule against difficult puzzles? ;-)

Comment: I think 'case-insensitive' should at least be ticked, to avoid people getting the right answer but the wrong combination of upper case and lower case

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is:

> Ronald Reagan, Jimmy Carter, Gerald Ford, Richard Nixon

(in this order, to make the colors match correctly.)

[Link to Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Ronald%20Reagan%2C%20Jimmy%20Carter%2C%20Gerald%20Ford%2C%20Richard%20Nixon&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CRonald%20Reagan%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CJimmy%20Carter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CGerald%20Ford%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CRichard%20Nixon%3B%2Cc0)